# Linq preserve and filter collection based on inner collection

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

If I have the following

```
public class Segment
    {
        private string sale;
        private IEnumerable<string> offers;

        // Properties for these

        // ctor
```

And this is the example data

```
var segment1 = new Segment("USD" new List<string>{"USD","ANZ"});
var segment2 =  new Segment1("GBP" new List<string>{"USD","ANZ"});
var segments = new List<Segment>{ segment1, segment2};
```

And I want to get a filter list of segments where any segment which has the same value in the sale as offer it is removed

How do i do this?

This is what I have so far but type is not correct

```
var _filtered = segments.Select(
    segment =>
        segment.Offers.Where(offer => offer != segment.Sale));
```

**Result should be**

A list of segments

List will be:

// Note USD removed

segment1 = "USD",{"ANZ"}

segment2 =  "GBP",{"USD","ANZ"}

Comment: Your title and explanation imply a matching segment would be removed/filtered from the list, but your expected outcome shows that an *offer* is removed from the segment.  Which is it?

Comment: offer. Sorry if not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I haven't tested, but:</strike>

```
var _filtered = segments.Select(x => 
       new Segment(x.Sale, x.Offers.Where(y => !y.Contains(x.Sale)))).ToList();
```

Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rWOCZi

Result:

> USD -> ANZ
>
> GBP -> USD,ANZ

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you need something following:

```
var _filtered = segments.Select(
    segment => new Segment(segment.Sale, segment.Offers.Where(o => o != segment.Sale).ToList());
```